# Configuring a Java HTTP servlet in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, jquery, web-config, netbeans-7.3

I've recently upgraded to Netbeans 7.3, and I quite don't get much of its project configuration and interface. For example, once I used to see the source packages with java classes, now I'm not able to see them only in the File panel. I have a package called batchUtility containing an HTTP servlet called batchQueryServlet.

I have to post a JSON to batchQueryServlet via the jQuery.ajax() function and I'm not able to map the servlet.

Since Netbeans 7.3 doesn't ship a config file, I've created one by myself clicking on the web-inf folder>new>web.xml file and wrote as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>batchQueryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>/batchUtility.batchQueryServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>batchQueryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/batchQueryServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

but still, when issuing the request, I get a 404 error:

```
  $.ajax({
                            url: "/batchQueryServlet",
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: json,
                            Accept: "text/html",
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                alert(data);
                            },
                            type: "POST"
                        });
```

Now, I'm pretty sure it doesn't find the class because if I call the servlet name I get a classNotFound exception. How could I fix that? (A quick and dirty solution would be using a JSP but I'd rather not do it).

PS: I use version 7.0.34 of Tomcat.

**EDIT** The problem was I should use a proper src/java path for storing my .java classes instead of a plain folder (this is the reason I couldn't see the packages). Now I've fixed it. Thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leading slash in

```
<servlet-class>/batchUtility.batchQueryServlet</servlet-class>
```

Remove it and things should work.

Change your Ajax `url:` to either `"batchQueryServlet"` or `"/web-app-name/batchQueryServlet"`

**EDIT**:

Once deployed your web application's folder structure should be like: (`/` indicates a directory)

```
tomcat-home/
 |- webapps/
   |- BatchWebApp/ //<-- Context-Root (Web-app's name)
     |- *.html, *.jsp etc.
     |- WEB-INF/
        |- web.xml
        |- lib/
          |- *.jar files
        |- classes/ //<-- ALL your servlets go here
          |- batchUtility/ //<-- with the required package/folder structure
            |- batchQueryServlet.class
```

If you're using an IDE (like Eclipse) it does the same for you.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Still, it doesn't work. However, I think I've understood what's the problem here, I have to set a context. When I post, I post to `http://localhost:8084/batchQueryServlet`, but I want it to be `http://localhost:8084/projectName/batchQueryServlet`.
I have a context.xml file, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/projectname"/>` and thought it could work but seems it won't. I tried to add a context path but it still posts against http://localhost:8084/batchQueryServlet :/

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Problem is, I still run in the ClassNotFound exception, as it doesn't find the batchQueryServlet. I've the batchUtility folder whitin the /app_name/ folder, but I've realized that classes cannot resolve classes within the same folder, I guess I've some problems with compilation.

Comment: Have a look at how your web application's folder structure look like once deployed in Tomcat.

Comment: Ah, missed it! Maybe I was trying too hard to earn your upvote. :)